# How to access global Array without using AppDelegate in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opencv, objective-c++

I have implemented `Opencv` in one of my project. In an `opencv` .mm file, I need to access the `appdelegate` object for global access of an array but it is giving `Linker Error` all the time (When I am trying to import the `AppDelegate` Class). So I have created an `NSObject` Class, still I can not access the Global Array which is created as the `@property` of the `NSObject` (I have imported the `NSObject` class in the .mm file). Array is giving the `NULL` value.
So where do I create the `Array` by which I can access the array in my whole project?

I can not use the `NSUSerDefaults` and `DocumentDirectory`. Because I want to save a lots of images and video links in that array, So I can not use `NSUserDefaults` and I don't want to use again the phone memory for the temp file as because I am picking the images from the `Photolibrary`, so `DocumentDirectory` is discarded, So Is there any way by which I can create the global array and access them from the `openCV` files i.e `objective CPP` files?

Comment: How about helping us with some written code?

Comment: @ Grzegorz Krukowski, Can you please provide some code, I am new bee in the opencv?

Comment: @ Marco Pace , I have given all the details what I have done so far, I can not provide you the code because Its a huge motion detector project, can you please help by any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make class as UserdataSingleton which overrides NSObject. which you can use all over your application to share data globally (for your case array). this code template may help you:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UserDataSingleton : NSObject
{
    @private
    NSArray *globalArray;
}
+(UserDataSingleton *) getInstance;  
-(void)saveInUserDatasingletonWithArray:(NSArray *)array;  
-(NSDictionary *)getGlobalArray;

@end
```

and implementation file will be some thing like:

```
#import "UserDataSingleton.h"  

@implementation UserDataSingleton  

static UserDataSingleton *userDataSingletonInstance;  


+(UserDataSingleton *) getInstance  
{ 

    if (userDataSingletonInstance == nil)   {
     userDataSingletonInstance = [[UserDataSingleton alloc] init]; 
}  
    return userDataSingletonInstance; 
}

-(void)saveInUserDatasingletonWithArray:(NSArray *)array 
{
    globalArray = array; 
}
-(NSDictionary *)getGlobalDictionary 
{ 
    return globalArray; 
} 
@end
```

================== usage:

```
#import "UserDataSingleton.h"
#define USERDATASINGLETON (UserDataSingleton *)[UserDataSingleton getInstance]
```

......................your code...

```
 NSArray *this_IS_Array_Populated_here_For_Global_Access = [NSArray alloc] initWith....];

[USERDATASINGLETON saveInUserDatasingletonWithArray:this_IS_Array_Populated_here_For_Global_Access];//you put your array for global access.
```

later some where in any other view or view controller you can get that global array for example lets say you have YourViewController class:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArrayFromWebResponse = [USERDATASINGLETON getGlobalArray];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that Objective C is a superset of C.  Thus, you can have regular C variables in your program. My favorite is to make a global variable for my appDelegate.  Put this in your app delegate's .h file:

```
MyAppDelegateClass * appDelegate;
```

(change "MyAppDelegateClass" to your appDelegate's class name) and put this in application: didFinishLaunchingWithOption: method in your app delegate's .m file:

```
    appDelegate = self;     // set universal global variable
```

Now just #import your app delegate's .h file and have access to your appDelegate from anywhere.

Comment: I have already implemented as you have written, I have also mentioned in the question. I am not able to create the app delegate object because when I am trying to access the AppDelegate class it is giving the Linker Error " linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: /Users/reshmimajumder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MotionSell-febbkqduifmexqbsswjsfakborau/Build/Intermediates/MotionSell.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpencvExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o 
    /Users/reshmimajumder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MotionSell-febbkqduifmexqbsswjsfakborau/Build/Intermediates/MotionSell.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpencvExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/MasterViewController.o
ld: 15 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Masterview Controller is one of the Objective CPP file, i.e it has the extention of .mm , and I am getting the above error when i am trying to import appdelegate class in .h file of MasterViewController..

Comment: Your error is that you have 15 duplicate symbols, which are probably listed beneath the link error you posted.  Did you add the file to your project twice, or do you have duplicate names inherent in your code?  This isn't about accessing global data - this is about your 15 duplicate names.  Find out why you have 15 things with duplicate names, and you'll find your problem.  Anything else is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create a singleton objet like  and access it from everywhere

Answer (score 0):

you could define a macro in your delegate like so:

```
#define sharedAppDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

and then in the class which you want to access your array import your AppDelegate class, boiler plate would be:

```
#import AppDelegate.h
```

and then just use:

```
NSArray *arrayYouWanted = [AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].yourPropertyArrayName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store it in NSUserDefaults if you want to persist it.